# How to enable solr spellchecker or suggester in the PHP PECL extension

Tags: php, solr, pecl

I cannot find any entries in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.solr.php) about enabling Spellchecker Component or Suggester. I can get spell suggestions by POST via

```
http://localhost:8112/solr/collection/spell?q=Citiz&wt=json&indent=true&spellcheck=true&spellcheck.collate=true
```

but how can I use spellchecker with the extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution myself. I wish there were more detailed tutorials about this extension.

```
   $client = new SolrClient($option);

   $client->setServlet(SolrClient::SEARCH_SERVLET_TYPE,'spell');

   $solrQuery  = new SolrQuery();

   $solrQuery->set('spellcheck','true');

   $solrQuery->setQuery($term);

   $query_response = $client->query($solrQuery);

   $data = $query_response->getResponse();
```